# Loop through files in batch

Tags: loops, batch-file, cmd

I'm using a script to store the content of a txt file in a variable. Now I have a lot of these files, and I want to go over every single one of them in a for loop.

```
Pseudo code:
for (i = 1, i < 100, i += 1) (
set var=file+i.txt
[do stuff with file]
)
```

How can I make something like this?

Answer (score 0):

cmd.exe supports a `for` loop, like:

```
for %c in ( file*.txt ) do process %c
```

It supports a fair number of options for things like getting only the base name of the file in question, so if (for example) you wanted to the `.txt` files and produce a file with the same base name and the extension changed to, say, `.dat`, that's pretty easy to do.

In this case, the apparent intent (gleaned from multiple comments) is to step through some files named `tweetNNN.txt`, where `NNN` is some number from 1 to 100. The content (not just the name) of that file is then to be passed on a cURL command line as data in a request.

The easiest way to do this is probably to use the `@` character on the cURL command line, something like this:

```
for /l %c in (1, 1, 100) do echo "language=english&text=" > stage.txt 
    && copy stage.txt + tweet%c.txt 
    && curl -d@stage.txt text-processing.com/api/sentiment/ >> results.txt
```

(Note: I've formatted this with line-breaks, but it needs to be entered as a single line).

I put together a quick test, using a couple of files:

```
tweet1.txt: "what complete crap. hated every minute"
tweet2.txt: "Best movie of the years. Loved it"
```

Running the previous command in a directory containing those two files produced a `results.txt` containing:

```
{"probability": {"neg": 0.82811145456964252, "neutral": 0.18962854533013332, "pos": 0.17188854543035748}, "label": "neg"}
{"probability": {"neg": 0.10467714372495518, "neutral": 0.080508941181180751, "pos": 0.89532285627504482}, "label": "pos"}
```

That seems a close enough fit with the content of the files that I think we can safely conclude that the text was analyzed as desired.

Comment: But how do I store the file in a variable?

Comment: You can store the file *name* in a variable like `set file_name = %c` (I'm guessing you don't want to try to stuff the entire contents of a file into an environment variable--unless the file is tiny, that would be a really bad idea).

Comment: I actually do want that, because the file is very tiny (it's a tweet)
the files are called "tweet (x)" where x is the number of tweets saved. Any idea how I could loop through them and save the contents of the files in a variable to use further on in the script?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that, at least without writing an actual program (e.g., in something like C or C++). You'd generally be better off writing something to process the file contents.

Comment: Well I use set var=tweet.txt to select the file and set /p var=<%var% to load the content into a variable. I just need to put the correct number to the selected tweet. I'm so close haha. So set file_name = tweet (%c) would be perfect

Comment: It's a shame 
"for /l %c (1, 1, 100) (
set var=tweet (%c).txt"
doesn't work

Comment: Why do you want the content of the file in an env variable? It's usually pretty easy to just process the file.

Comment: I'm running a sentiment analysis using curl:
curl -d "language=dutch&text=%var%" http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/>uitkomst.txt

Comment: It uses the content of an exported tweet in a txt file (%var%)

Comment: @JanJansen: cURL supports putting the data into a file, then passing the file name, and concatenates pieces together correctly, so you can do something like `curl -d"language=dutch" -d@tweetN.txt ...` (where `tweetN.txt` is the name of the file containing the tweet you want to analyze.

Comment: I just can't seem to figure out how this works. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: I just want to figure out how I can loop trough tweetN.txt where N goes from 1 to 100